# How to maintain focus on menu after clicking a menu command

Tags: windows, menu

- Simple version

Is there any way to maintain focus on menu after clicking a menu command?

- Detailed version

Specifically, I've made a menu with some menu item with checked property. The problem is that each time I click checked menu item the menu lose its focus. It can be pretty annoying when there is a number of menu item with checked property and I want to manipulate them at once.

The most elegant solution for the problem would be maintaining focus on menu, but I can't find a way to apply it. Is it possible? And if so, what's the way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there would a solution for it, sooner or later you will enter a situation in which a numerical or string property is changed via the menu, and then it becomes even impossible to keep the focus on the menu (while the dialog requesting the number or string is on the screen).

The first, simple alternative would be to put the checkable menu items on a toolbar or ribbon (just like Word does with Bold, Italic, Underline, ...).  Numerical/string properties can then also be added on the toolbar or ribbon.

A second alternative could be to have a more complete configuration dialog in which the user can change all the configuration items.  The configuration dialog can co-exist with the current checkable items, so users simply changing one check and users changing many properties all get a quick way of doing what they want.

You might also pose this question on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ (this sibling site is more oriented towards good user interface practices).